# QTableView get list of rows with similar column values/Data

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) with data generated from .csv file. The [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) has column called Date ([QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html)) that covers over a month. I want to select a date and split the data for that date from the [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), so I can summarize and average the values in the other columns.

Similar to SQL Table Queries, or to this c# LINQ syntax:

```
var result = context.data.Where(n => n.date == date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your table view data and extract the information you need. As a demonstration please look at the given example:

```
void findDates(QTableView *table, const QDateTime &date)
{
  auto model = table->model();
  const int dateColumn = 1; // The column with the dates data

  for (int row = 0; row < model->rowCount(); ++row)
  {
    auto idx = model->index(row, dateColumn);
    auto data = idx.data();
    auto d = data.toDateTime();

    // Comparison of dates
    if (d > date)
    {
      // Do something
    }
    else
    {
      // Do something else
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example and the idea I got from it, solved my problem, so thank you.